# Get color from jscolor

Tags: javascript, code-generation, jscolor

I am using jscolor.js from http://jscolor.com

The function below is what I used before to add the users input to a code generator. They typed in the hex colour of their choice and it would get added to the code generator.

```
function changeOutlineColour(){
   var jj_input4 = document.getElementById('jj_input4').value;
   document.getElementById('outlinecolour').innerHTML = jj_input4;
   document.getElementById('jj_preview2').style.outlineColor = '#' + jj_input4;
}
```

This is where the code gets added to, inbetween the `span` tags

```
<div class="jj_yourcode">
    <p>#<span id="outlinecolour"></span>;</p>
</div>
```

Now that I am using jscolor, the hex code doesnt get added the the generator so my question is, what changes do I have to make to the function so that is does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out using a button

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" onClick="submitColour()">Set Colour</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitColour(){
    var jj_input4 = document.getElementById('jj_input4').value;
    document.getElementById('outlinecolour').innerHTML = jj_input4;
}
```